# Alamofire 5 headers GET method returns invalid json in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 5. I have GET request with headers parameters. But when I am called in postman, it returns the right json. In Alamofire it returns wrong json like below:

```
success({
   "country_id" = 3;
    "customer_id" = 1;
    "language_id" = 1;
    profile =    {
    address1 = "";
    address2 = "";
   }
 })
```

Here is my postman json

```
{ "type_id": 1,
"country_id": 3,
"language_id": 1,
"customer_id": 1,
"parent_user_id": null,
"profile": {
    "image": "xiOHhaFfBXaMHewCwznPjejMPWrle48KEiDh75eh.png",
    "mob2": "",
 }
}
```

Here is my code I used for GET data:

```
func getProfileInfo() {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "YumaSession": "424142411"
    ]

    AF.request(url, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON  { response in
       print(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let responseData):

        case .failure(let error):
            Custom_Progress_Bar.hide_progress_dialog()
            print("error--->",error)
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me what is the wrong my code.

Comment: Let `reponseData` seems to be a `NSDictionary`, ie, already parsed. You might be able to do: `let json = responseData as? [String: Any]` and use it, no?

Comment: can you help me parse like json: success({
   "country_id" = 3;
    "customer_id" = 1;
    "language_id" = 1;
    profile =    {
    address1 = "";
    address2 = "";
   }
 })

Answer (score 0):

What you're printing there is not the JSON, it's the printed description of the `Result`, which will not look like JSON. Print `response.debugDescription` or use `debugPrint(response)` to see what your body data really looks like. Additionally, if you're using a different `YumaSession` value, I would expect a different profile response.